# ASP.NET Core console app cannot find controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have created a simple .NET Core console project that includes ASP.NET core, as below:

MyProject.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.1.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

And in my Program.cs:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseUrls("http://localhost:1234")
            .Build()
            .Run();
    }
}
```

In my Startup.cs I have:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

And a single controller in a Controllers folder:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [Route("Home/Index")]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return Ok("Hello from index");
    }
}
```

But nothing I can do seems to make it hit my controller.
The logs are showing that requests to `http://localhost:1234/Home/Index` are coming through Kestrel, but 404ing.

What am I missing? I have also tried specifying routes, but have had no luck in making it find the controller.

Comment: Include `[HttpGet]` on the action or just replace `Route` with `[HttpGet("Home/Index")]` since not using a view. Finally shouldn't Main be `public`

Comment: Why don't you just start from the default project all of this is included for you

Comment: @johnny5 We need to incorporate this into an existing project; this was a proof of concept.

Comment: @Nkosi Neither changing the `[Route("Home/Index")]` to `[HttpGet("Home/Index")]` or adding `[HttpGet]` has corrected the problem; the logs still show 404.

Comment: And you are certain that main is being invoked?

Comment: @KommandantKeen yes, so create a new project and copy the home controller over.

Comment: @Nkosi Yes, main is called, and I can debug it. If I add my own function to perform at the end of the stack, it handles every request:
`app.UseMvc();
            app.Run(context =>
            {
                return context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello");
            });`

Comment: Are you trying to use mvc or webapi?

Comment: @johnny5 WebApi, I guess. I thought there was less of a distinction in ASP.NET Core. I tried creating a new project, and copying over the WebAPI controller (decorated with an `ApiControllerAttribute` but still no luck. The new project is using IIS Express however, and I don't want that in my project.

Comment: Try Adding a route prefix to your controller

Comment: @johnny5 No luck. I have changed my project back to a dotnet core 2.0 (not 2.1) app, and changed the reference from `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.1.1" />` to `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.8" />` and it fixed the problem.

Thank you for your help. 
That said, I would like to know what's different.

Comment: Kommandant so this works fine with the old assemblies? Now that’s weird

Comment: @johnny5 Correct. I'd like to get to the bottom of it, too; EOL for 2.0 is September.

Comment: Ooo I might why, this project was an upgrade from 1.0 correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m not sure if this is the reason why but your kestrel is using the old 1.1 version,  in order for certain process to run properly such as migrations, which relies on duck typing you should declare a BuildWebHost method:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
}
```

There’s more information in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x). If this doesn’t work I would create a new project and move things across manually.  The only other issue I could think of would be your package manager cache is messed up or you have too many run times installed on your machine

Answer (score 0):

Remove:

> .UseUrls("http://localhost:1234")

That could be as a result of separate URLs in the launchSettings.json

Afterwards add the routing and endpoints to the middleware,

```
app.UseRouting();

app.UseEndpoints(e =>
         e.MapControllerRoute( name: "default",
          pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}")
        
);
```

Also, register the mvc service

> services.AddMvc();